# Loadrunner, web_reg_save match the RB first

Tags: loadrunner

I think the answer is no - but just in case 
I need to get the formid for an Agent from the following dynamic list in which the order is not always the same

```
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=33,Pilot 
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=34,Customer
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=35,Agent
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=36,Cleaner
```

but could also be :-

```
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=33,Cleaner
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=34,Customer
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=35,Pilot
/always/the/same/and/very/long/not/always/in/the/same/order/formid=36,Agent
```

Is there a smart way to do this ?
How do you search when the RB is the unique part
Can you swap the LB & RB so you can match the RB first, then work backwards eg:-

```
web_reg_save_param("cAgentFormID", 
"RB/IC=,Agent"
"LB/IC=,formid=",   
LAST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web_reg_save_param function should work just as you want it too, even if the unique part is the right boundry. In this occurance the function uses the most recent left boundry match, not the first occurance of it in the page.

Here's a quote from the official documentation on this function that describes what you are talking about:

> web_reg_save_param results in a simple search for the next occurrence after the most recent left boundary. For example, if you have defined the left boundary as the character `{` and the right boundary as the character `}', then with the following buffer c is saved:

```
      {a{b{c}
```

The left and right boundaries have been located. Since embedded boundaries are not supported, the `}' is matched to the most recent`{` appearing just before the c. The ORD attribute is 1. There is only one matching instance.

Comment: Damn - I needed to read that carefully before it sunk in. Thanks v much